# Does server code involving both sending and receiving have to be asynchronous?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, python-asyncio

I'm getting started with websockets. Trying to write a python server for a browser based (javascript) client.

I have also never really done asynchronous programming before (except "events"). I was trying to avoid it - I have searched and searched for an example of websocket use that did *not* involve importing tornado or asyncio. But I've found nothing, even the "most basic examples" do it.

So now I'm internalising it, but clear it up for me - is "full duplex" server code necessarily asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full-duplex servers are necessarily *concurrent*. In Tornado and `asyncio`, concurrency is based on the asynchronous programming model, so if you use a websocket library based on one of those packages, your code will need to be asynchronous.

But that's not the only way: full-duplex websockets could be implemented in a synchronous way by dedicating a thread to reading from the connection (in addition to whatever other threads you're using). I don't know if there are any python websocket implementations that support this kind of multithreading model for full-duplex, but that's how Go's websocket implementation works for example.

That said, the asynchronous/event-driven model is a natural fit for websockets (it's how everything works on the javascript side), so I would encourage you to get comfortable with that model instead of trying to find a way to work with websockets synchronously.